# Yajra laravel datatables oracle disable escaping string

Tags: laravel, datatables

How to disable escaping string in yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle? version: "dev-master"
http://take.ms/hKGEI

Comment: You want to enable html tags and display it as a link?

Comment: @Rashad Yes it is

Comment: I checked, it is enabled by default. Maybe you have a middleware, that escapes the string?

Comment: please, provide your datatable codes.

Comment: @Rashad It happend after I updated Laravel from 5.3 to 5.4 version. Му code http://take.ms/isObB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to your question. After updating yajra/laravel-datatables-orakle package to version 7.* - All columns escaped by default to protect from XSS attack. To allow columns to have an html content, use rawColumns api. [doc](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/upgrade)